# PHP Select Login Error

Tags: php

I'm just a newbie in PHP and I need to create a php Login form but It have a syntax error   saying  `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 18`
maybe you can help me on this tnx!

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","reservation");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to Database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else
  {
  }

if ($_POST["SUBMIT"]="SUBMIT")
{
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password =$_POST['password'];
$sql ="SELECT * FROM usersaccount where='$username' and password ='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
{
echo "success";
}
//mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM usersaccount ='$username' and password ='$password'"` ??? missed `where`

Comment: You need to check for errors when you query, before trying to use `$result`. If you did, you would have been notified that your query has a syntax error.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **`SELECT`** statement is wrong ... should be

```
SELECT * FROM `usersaccount` WHERE `username` ='$username' and `password` ='$password'";
                                   ---------- // Here.. Added the column name
```

You are not providing the column name for `username` field. That was your issue. Since you are matching results with condition you need a **`WHERE`** clause too !

<sup>Disclaimer : Stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Switch to MySQLi or PDO instead.</sup>

Comment: PRETTY STUPID OF ME TNX!

Answer (score 1):

It means your query (i.e., `$sql`) is broken. You are comparing a table to a string, when you should be using a `WHERE` clause. Also, `password` is a reserved word; escape it, like this:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM usersaccount WHERE `username` ='$username' and `password` ='$password'";
```

Also, you are **wide open** to SQL injection; you need prepared statements.

Comment: `password` isn't a reserved word, I've never had to escape it in my queries.

Comment: Hmm... MySQL Workbench treats it as one. Will have to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) you have to do this:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","reservation");
//...
$query = "SELECT * FROM usersaccount ='$username' and password ='$password'";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query)) {
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);/* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);/* store result */
    printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt));
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);/* close statement */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message is reporting that its first parameter is a boolean, you should take a closer look at that first parameter.

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Read [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) : If it works, `mysqli_query()` returns a `mysqli_result()` or FALSE (a boolean) if it doesn't work.  So, your query didn't work and it returned a boolean.

You should probably check the outcome of executing your query and, if it fails, you should show the error message generated:

```
if ( $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) === FALSE ) {
  printf("Invalid query: %s\nWhole query: %s\n", mysqli_error, $sql);
  exit();
}
```